# Overflow auto on flex div cuts the image from top

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, css-transforms

I have implemented the image viewer, where I can rotate the image and can be able to do zoom-in and zoom-out.

Zoom-in and zoom-out work well and rotate as well.
But when I rotate the image and the zoom it, the image gets cut from the top.

I have tried adding an absolute position to image and giving it top:0, but neither that worked.

Can anyone help?

```css
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.modal-container .modal-window {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    // Optional support to confirm scroll behavior makes sense in IE10
    //-ms-flex-direction: column;
    //-ms-flex-align: center;
    //-ms-flex-pack: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.modal-container .modal-window .modal-content {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
 margin: auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  flex:none;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-window">
        <img class="modal-content" src="http://www.hislider.com/templates/erishorizontal/dataimages/7.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abx8c13j/16/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.modal-container .modal-window {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    // Optional support to confirm scroll behavior makes sense in IE10
    //-ms-flex-direction: column;
    //-ms-flex-align: center;
    //-ms-flex-pack: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.modal-container .modal-window .modal-content {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
  transform-origin: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
 margin: auto;
  flex:none;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-window">
        <img class="modal-content" src="http://www.hislider.com/templates/erishorizontal/dataimages/7.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.modal-container .modal-window .modal-content**

I changed only this area. Use fixed dimensions for rotation and scale events

Comment: I have to zoom the image, so I can't give it a width or height in pixels.

Comment: This doesn't work if your image size is bigger than parent div's size

Comment: i don't understand. Tell me that what you want please with a example.

Comment: My requirement is to rotate an image and zoom it. When end user zooms the image, it has to be double its height and width. so I can't give a fixed dimension. Plus if you will increase max-width and max-height in your solution, it won't work either.
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/abx8c13j/89/